# Binary Search Tree "stack" explanation

Tags: c#, return, binary-search-tree

I have a very simple implemention of BST in C#. The code:

```
class Node
{
    public int? value;
    public Node parent;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;

    public Node(int? value, Node parent = null)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}

class BST
{
    public Node root;
    public List<Node> tree = new List<Node>();

    public BST(int? value = null)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            this.root = new Node(value);
            this.tree.Add(this.root);
        }
    }

    public Node insert(int value)
    {
        Node node = this.root;

        if (node == null)
        {
            this.root = new Node(value);
            this.tree.Add(this.root);

            return this.root;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (value > node.value)
            {
                if (node.right != null)
                {
                    node = node.right;
                }
                else
                {
                    node.right = new Node(value, node);
                    node = node.right;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (value < node.value)
            {
                if (node.left != null)
                {
                    node = node.left;
                }
                else
                {
                    node.left = new Node(value, node);
                    node = node.left;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        BST superTree = new BST(15);
        superTree.insert(14);
        superTree.insert(25);
        superTree.insert(2);
    }
}
```

My Question is regarding the "Insert" method of the BST class.

How exactly its "return" work when I just call it in the main method?
How does it know to put that "node" on the "left"? I am not referencing "root.left" anywhere but somehow it gets properly inserted.

I realized at some point that some kind of recursion occurs there, but its been like 6 hours and I still can't understand how this method properly works.

I appreaciate any explanation of that "insert" method.Thanks.

Comment: I don’t understand the question. The “return” works as any other, returns the node and it’s not used at all here. There are two references to left node in the code. Did you run it line by line in a debugger to see what happens in it? There’s a loop that traverses the tree and sees where to insert.

Comment: Initially node left is null so you reach this line of code : if (node.left != null) which puts new node on the left.

Comment: The function Insert is not recursive. The while loop traverses the tree from the root until finding a suitable terminal node and creates at the end of that node a new node containing the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Node node = this.root;
```

Your code always starts with the root, because of this line.  It's only after `node` is no longer null that `node` be re-assigned to something other than root.  The rest of the code works on `node.left`, but because your code begins with `root` as above, `node.left` is actually referencing `root` at the start.

Comment: Note that `node` is not a copy of the `root` object. Since the `Node` type is a reference type, both variables point to the same object. So, assigning a new node to `node.Left` is the same as assigning it to `root.Left`.

Comment: Are you sure that "Node" is a reference type, because it is a class which I created without inheriting any other classes(interface etc.)?

Comment: All classes are reference types.

Comment: Structs are value types, classes are reference types.

Comment: OMFG references actually completely explain how this dark magic works. Thank you :).

Comment: @Lunster I now understand what you mean, but not completely. What do you mean " It's only after that node is full"

Comment: When it's no longer `null`.  You should to step through your code and watch the values of the variables change with each statement, do you know how to do that?  It's very helpful to understanding program flow.  I've edited my answer to be a little more precise but I feel like the real problem is learning how to debug (it's very powerful and easy to just step through code, hover over variables and see how program state changes with each statement - especially with code that repeats)

Comment: @Lunster Yes I know how to. I actually went over it step by step many times. But I just couldn't come up with an explanation how come "root.left" = "node.left" until the mention of references. 
I know what what the code does, I just don't understand how. That is all there is. That is why it is not very useful to me just seeing how some variables get filled.